# Django Choices based on Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I am wondering if there is a way to use a list that is stored in a foreignkey as the choices for a charfield.

Here is what I have right now but it is not working.

```
priority = models.ForeignKey(SLAs)
prioritylevel = models.CharField(choices=priority.details)
```

It says that the ForeignKey has no attribute 'details'

If this has been answered, please point me the correct direction.

Thanks :)

Comment: `priority` is a `ForeignKey` at that scope, not a model.

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to do this? You can always access the data via `priority.details`, I don't understand why you need to copy it to another model.

Comment: In the foreignkey there is a list that would define a choice drop which would be in details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want use this in forms?

So you can do smth like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    prioritylevel = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=OtherModel.objects.values('level'))
```

and in model this will just `CharField`. It this solve your problem?

Comment: {'name':'Jonh'}
How to get only value Jonh?

Comment: @PhokChanrithisak use ```.values_list('name', flat=True)``` then